# Can anyone please clarify these?

Tags: web

For web hosting of an Enterprise application do we need web server or Application server?
When application server can serve all protocols for client requests and responses why web server is introduced ?
Can application server be running in a web server so that Enterprise application can be accessed in WWW ?

Please help, these are my all time hunting doubts Thank You...

Comment: web server = host html, app server = host an application

Answer (score 0):

You could let your application server be your webserver as well, but you generally shouldn't.

Two reasons come to mind (maybe there are more):

1. **security**: Your application server might have additional ports/service endpoints/interfaces etc. which are accessed locally and you don't want to expose them to the Web. (You could achieve results with a suitable firewall, but the webserver adds another layer of protection).
2. **performance**: If there is no dedicated web server, your application server has to serve static content (images, static pages etc.) in addition to performing the business logic. Having dedicated web servers helps in distribute the load.